# how to use page break in sql?

Tags: sql

is there is any way to use page break in sql.actually am generating report with the help of shell script spool command.i need to break the report to next page once it got reach at line number 35. how to write sql statement for this?

Answer (score 2):

You should do this in your calling application, pagination of output is not something SQL is suited for.

Comment: Agreed; he should read the results with a small program and use that to paginate.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that LIMIT is what you need. like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 10
(This will display the first 10 results from the database)

SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 5, 5
(This will show records 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10)

SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 20, 10
(This will return 10 records from 21st record. That is from 21st record to 30th  record)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Well, he asked for a way to do this in SQL and this is the way I know. I normally do this in the application so I only know that LIMIT exists. If it is supported or not, I honestly don't know... But thanks for your enlightment :)

Comment: it's not supported in SQL Server

Comment: could u please tell me how to use page break in sql? and print dynamic heading in each page?

Comment: well, you could use variables with your queries. I'll give an example in PHP. Something like:
$startIndex = 0;
$numRows = 35;
Your query would be: $query = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT".$startIndex.", ".$numRows;
Then set the startIndex for the new position $startIndex += $numRows; Of course this is very superficial. You should check other stuff like if you are going forwards or backwards, and the number of items in the table so you can create an index like: $numEntries = "SQL...COUNT" and $numPages = $numEntries / $numRows and for each page the index would be: $startIndex = $pageNum * $numRows